# Which book, if any, describes the fate of the Brennan Monster in the Ringworld book series?

Tags: larry-niven, known-space

First introduced in Larry Nivens Known Space novel *Protector*, was the fate of the Brennan Monster, Earth's first Human Protector, ever revealed in the Ringworld book series? If so, which book tells the tale?

Comment: I believe there is some notice of the subsequent consequences in *[Destroyer of Worlds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destroyer_of_Worlds_%28novel%29)*, which isn't to say that there is a lot of detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean Brennan or Truesdale?

Brennan's fate is described in [Protector:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protector_%28novel%29)

> Brennan and Truesdale travel to the planet Home to distract the Pak fleet from Earth, on the way Truesdale realizes Brennan's plan is to infect everyone on Home with Tree-of-Life, so he kills Brennan to try to prevent that from happening.

What happens to Truesdale...

> and the rest of the Protectors after everyone on Home is either killed or converted to a Protector by the Tree-of-Life infection and they get ready to fight off the Pak fleet...

is not covered in any of the Ringworld novels.

(This could probably just be a comment, and given how old Protector is, probably doesn't need the spoiler markup, but just in case...)

Comment: Good answer. I indeed meant Brennan, but it has been so long since I read that particular book, the details are murky. I read the 'of World series, which prompted my question, but I neglected the middle portion of the series after Ringworlds Children. I guess it's time to dust off Protector and give it another read.

Comment: I'd still like Niven to get around to explaining what happened on Home after the events in Protector...

Comment: @Ward I just recalled...there is a short story that covers some of it in one of the recent Man--Kzin wars collections. But there is no way I can recall *which one* and my copies are all in storage...

Comment: @dmckee It's "Teacher's Pet" from Man-Kzin XI, the first of the Peace Corben stories.